# Tags are closed but compiler throws "Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <img>"

Tags: reactjs

I get this error, I tried to understand where the tags are not closed, but they seem all to be closed.

I tried to close all tags, they look all closed

```
return(
  <div>
  <h3>Popular Movies</h3>

  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px180/" alt="Imagem de capa do card"><img/>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">
      {!!this.state.popularMovies && this.state.popularMovies[0].title}
      </h5>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Watch</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
)
```

It is expected to appear no error messages.

Comment: UPDATE: after self close IMG tag i get this error: "Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX."

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons.

1. `<img />` should be self-closing. (No end `</img>`).
2. You have `<img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px180/" alt="Imagem de capa do card"><img/>` where the first `<img` isn't closing and the 2nd one is empty.

Please refer to [MDN documentation on img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) for more info.

Comment: now i get this: "Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX."

Comment: That's a totally separate error unrelated to the original question. Would you update the post with the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

`img` tags are self closing, especially in `React`

```
<img className="...your classes" src="/source-path" />
```

Comment: now i get this: "Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX."

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the closing image tag and just write it as:

`<img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px180/" alt="Imagem de capa do card" />`

Also in react your style tags must be wrapped in double brackets:

`<div class="card" style={{width: '18rem'}}>`

And for any styles that require a dash in the name, the name must be converted to camel case letters, for instance:

`margin-right: '15px'` turns into `marginRight: '15px'`

Comment: Then approve his answer as best solution ^^